# Temporarily locked out ... how long is a "short while"?

Tags: login

I was trying to login to an old Wordpress site I had forgotten the password too, had too many attempts at the password and got myself temporarily locked out.

I have since reset the password, (directly in the MySQL database), but still can't login because of my "temporarily lock out".

Wordpress keeps telling me to "**please try back in a short while**" ... *it has been 3 hours already!*

I have googled this extensively, and no one seems to know how long that "short while" is...

Comment: As far as I know this is not a core WordPress feature but most likely a (security) plugin such as limit login attempts. Just deactivate that plugin and you're good to go (you can do so by renaming the plugin's folder via FTP)

Comment: Great advice @kero, I have "wordfence" installed, disabled that and I'm back in!

Answer (score 1):

This is not core functionality but a "feature" of my security plugin (Wordfence, in this instance). Disabled the plugin by using FTP to rename the folder and was able to log back in.